# Objective-C's dynamic advantages in Cocoa development?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

So from my understanding (one of) the biggest allures of Obj-C is the dynamic, message-passing runtime.

How's this and other features overall beneficial to Cocoa development?  Why was Obj-C used for Cocoa dev and not C++/C?

Basically I'm trying to understand how such language features are actually beneficial in terms of when actually solving a particular problem in terms of OSX or iOS application.

Comment: Let me clarify: if Cocoa was implemented in C++ or Java would any features of the framework be substantially different? or outright not possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Major pieces of the Cocoa frameworks are difficult (not impossible, of course) in less dynamic languages. Key-value coding (which makes use of dynamic dispatch and runtime class and hierarchy modification) are very hard to do in compile-time bound (method-calling) languages. Core Data's synthesis of attribute getters/setters is a similar example of Objective-C's dynamic messaging (and dynamic runtime) making things much easier.

Objective-C's dynamic messaging was designed *specifically* to solve the dependency problem in large projects. Whereas a compile-time bound language like C++ requires that dependent modules be recompiled together, Objective-C's runtime-bound messaging means that you don't *always* have to re-compile everything. At the time of NeXT's decision to use Objective-C over (the, at the time, immature C++), that was a major factor in developer sanity. It still makes large systems easier to manage (though, again, it's certainly not impossible in C++ or Java or ..., just much harder).

Comment: The Cocoa-Java bridge's lifespan and the prevalence of KVO/KVC are entirely orthogonal....

Comment: @bbum, thanks for the insider knowledge. I'd heard (though never officially) that things like KVO were too hard in the Java bridge. Any chance you can enlighten us on the reasons for its deprecation?

Answer (score 0):

My two cents:

1. Single Inheritance: Reduces Coupling of classes yet, some (myself included) just think its a handicap.
2. Has protocols: C++ doesn't.
3. Messaging system: It's not per say an advantage, but it is different than the dot syntax use in C++.
4. Strict super set of C: C++ is just mostly a super set of C.
5. You can use Objective-C++ which gives you the power of C++ with Objective-C.

Comment: In C++ you would typically use multiple inheritance to implement an interface (aka protocol).

Answer (score 0):

I've been using C++ and Objective-C++ extensively. My take is that the messaging system solves a lot of issues. A lot of design patterns/hacks in C++ are trivial in Objective-C.

The one issue is that the messaging system (correct me if I'm wrong) is insecure in that the messages are passed as text. It also seems a lot easier to reverse engineer an objective-c program.

Comment: Selectors include a textual name (the `initWithFoo:bar:baz:` part), but the arguments are passed the same as to a C function (because the method implementation *is* a C function). I'm not sure what you mean by “the messaging system … is insecure”. You're correct that Objective-C classes are very easy to reverse-engineer; all you need is class-dump.

Comment: Any examples of design patterns/hacks which are trivial in Obj-C over C++?

Comment: Messages are not passed as text. Message dispatch consists of looking up pointers to code in method tables, pushing parameters on the stack and then calling a function pointer.

Answer (score -3):

The answer to your question is not technical, but historical.

Steve Jobs leaves Apple and founds NExT based on Objective C a new improved Object-Oriented dynamic typed language - a giant improve to C, then returns to Apple and Apple buys NExT and uses it's core to design MAC OS X. MAC OS X and iOS frameworks are thus built in Objective-C.

Now for the technical details is a different matter.

Dynamic typing for example brings up a rainbow of programmatic potential, but takes a great chunk of debugging work from compile time to runtime, i.e. since the language is flexible it let's you go away with running apps that not necessarily are concise and/or coherent.

On the other hand Java solves all the problems hunting Objective-C and gives you a non dynamic  language with introspection - allowing you all the power of dynamic typing and keeping a heavily rigid set of rules that pretty much relieve you from 98% of your debugging time.

C and C++ are bad languages of the past
Objective-C is a good language from the past
Java / C# are modern languages

It's being a descent into hell to come from extensive Java / C# programming and having to deal again with sloppier compilers to work with ObjC, but hey, that's my penalty for wanting to develop for the iPhone.

Comment: This is a nonsensical rant against Objective-C, not an answer to the question asked.  What is "since the language is flexible it let's you go away with running apps that not necessarily are concise and/or coherent" supposed to mean anyway?  Perhaps you should spend a little more time with the language in practice before judging it.

Comment: No, it's neither nonsensical nor rant. If you see my post as an aggression towards ObjC you missed my point by miles, and I regret that. However that doesn't mean there aren't several design flaws in ObjC when looking at today's perspective and knowledge of computer languages and compilers. What I said is not a mere opinion, little less a ranted one, it's an experienced fact and that's independent of this being an ObjC forum with ObjC programmers.